# codedeploy on boto does not allow content overwrite

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-code-deploy

I'm using boto3==1.20.42.
Here is my code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('codedeploy')

response = client.create_deployment(
    applicationName='MyWebsite',
    deploymentGroupName='MySiteDeploymentGroup',
    revision={
        'revisionType': 'S3',
        's3Location': {
            'bucket': 'my-code-deploy',
            'key': 'drupal-deploy2.zip',
            'bundleType': 'zip',
        },
    },
    description='Deploying updates',
    ignoreApplicationStopFailures=False,
    fileExistsBehavior='OVERWRITE'
)
print(response)
```

What I expect is that it overwrite the contents as I specified above but I observe that it is not overwriting files as you can see in the used deployment settings image below:
[image]

Can anyone help me figure out how to overwrite contents programmatically with boto?

Answer (score 1):

`fileExistsBehavior` is **per deployment setting**. You can't set a default value for that. For each new deploymentyou have to explicitly specify that it should be `OVERWRITE`.

Comment: Hi. That's what I'm trying to do in the code. The screenshot is just the setting used in the automatic deployment showing the proof that it did not actually set the overwrite flag.

Comment: I mean the screenshot is the result of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code above seems to work but if you open the settings of a previous deployment on the AWS console, it does not show the flag as selected which lead to me thinking that it did not overwrite.